# Checking for ingredients in a meal you order in a restaurant

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, question-words

At a restaurant, I'd like to make sure that a meal doesn't have milk or cheese. What would be the right way of asking this?:

"Do you add milk or cheese to this dish?" ("meal" or "plate"?)
"Does this meal have milk or cheese?"

Thank you.

Comment: Does [the (dish)] have milk or cheese in it? That's the idiomatic way to say it.

Comment: Or "Does it contain any milk or cheese?"

Comment: @KateBunting I specifically did not use contain as that is more technical. Of course, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these examples are correct.  However, if the goal is to avoid a lactose intolerant situation, you might achieve even better results with the term "dairy."

Example:
"Does this meal have dairy in it?"

If you are trying to avoid animal products for religious or other purposes, use the term "vegan."

Example:
"Is this meal vegan?"